# Print emojis in windows terminal Python

Tags: python, pycharm, emoji, python-idle, windows-terminal

Here's the code:

```
import emoji
import time

print("\U0001F600")
time.sleep(50)
```

Here's the output when I run in the python idle shell thingo:
[image: output in idle shell]

Here's the output when I run the program in windows terminal thingo:
[image: output in windows terminal]

I've got this game thing I'm working on for an assignment, and I've simply just copy pasted emojis into the print function, and when I run it in PyCharm, it works just like in idle shell. But when I turn it into an executable using the pyinstaller module thing, it just shows ? instead of the emoji.

By the way, I'm not that advanced in this kinda thing, so I'd appreciate if someone could explain how to fix this problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work in the normal cmd console. If so, you need the
[Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

[image: My results]

(In addition, you do not need the emoji module for your method)

Comment: Hey! I've installed windows terminal, but when I run the .exe file it still uses the old cmd thing, how can I make the default for .exe to be the windows terminal? :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to exchange the standard cmd console for the terminal. The only options are either to use the terminal or to write a gui.